# Breaking Outer For-loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I have two for-loops in python inside while loop as follows:

```py
while ..
  for ..
    for ..
      if condition == True:
         break
```

I want to break the first for-loop once the condition in the if statement is met, How can I achieve it, it appears that break is only terminating inner for loop and not outer, I want outer for-loop to be terminated.

Comment: put the code in a function then use `return` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the solution I would use for C programming, a `goto` command (haters gonna hate), doesn't exist in Python.

I've encountered this situation as well and the best solution I know is the following:

```
while ...
    breakLoop = False
    for ...:
        for ...:
            if condition:
                breakLoop = True
                break
        if breakLoop:
            break
```

Comment: @metron, if you found my answer useful, feel free to upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

use a flag to inform outer breaker:

```
while ..
  for ..
    should_break = False
    for ..
      if condition == True:
         should_break = True
         break
    if should_break: break
```

Answer (score 0):

I would attempt to refactor this so you don't have so many nested loops. Maybe move the inner loop into a function? Otherwise you can add the break after the inner loop as well.

```
while ..
  for ..
    for ..
      if condition == True:
         break
    if condition == True:
      break
```